# list_display of the model with foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following django model.
In the django admin model of TestCase table, in its list_display, i want to display the most recent comment and the modifier name of Remark table.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Release(models.Model):
    title        = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    start_time   = models.DateField('Release Start Date')
    release_date = models.DateField('Release Ended Date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class TestCase(models.Model):
    query       = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ksq_id      = models.IntegerField()
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    release     = models.ForeignKey(Release) # Release can have many test cases

    def __str__(self):
        return self.query

class Remark(models.Model):
    owner       = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    module      = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    comment     = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    modified_ts = models.DateTimeField('date modified', auto_now=True)
    modifier    = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    testcase    = models.ForeignKey(TestCase) # Testcase can have many Re
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from kramer_release.models import Release, TestCase, Remark

class RemarksInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Remark
    extra = 0 

class RemarkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('owner', 'module', 'testcase_query')

    def testcase_query(self, obj):
        return obj.testcase.query

class TestCaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RemarksInline]
    list_display = ('query', 'status')

admin.site.register(Release)
admin.site.register(TestCase, TestCaseAdmin)
admin.site.register(Remark, RemarkAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can defined a function to get the latest comment as part of you admin class, something like:

```
class TestCaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RemarksInline]
    list_display = ('query', 'status', 'latest_comment')

    def latest_comment(self, obj):
        remarks = Remark.objects.filter(testcase=obj).order_by('-modified_ts')
        if remarks:
            return '%s - %s' % (remarks[0].comment, remarks[0].modifier)
        return None
```

[see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the comment and modifier to be two different fields. I can extend your code to two functions. Isn't this operation costly since it will do two queries on each row rendering? Is there any other simple or elegant way?

Comment: ah ok, yes definitely costly, esp. when you have lots of row showing.

Comment: This query can be more concisely expressed as `obj.remark_set.latest('modified_ts')` - although that won't help with the multiple queries. I'm not sure there's much that can be done about that. Doing multiple columns without repeating the query in two different functions is complicated, you'd probably have to override the admin template.

Comment: Is there some problem in my model schema which makes this complex? My use case looks like a common problem.